# How to use txfont in plain TeX

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, txfonts

I'm trying to insert one font from txfont package in my plain TeX file, but I cannot understand some aspects of this font distribution.

The font I would use is the txmi1; so, how can TeX use this font? The distribution gives only its tfm file, and there is no pfb file related to it. The only pfb files I can use are the txmia and rtxmi ones, in which the slots for the lowercase letters (a,b,...,z) are empty. Thus, even if I write the simpliest line `\font\aaa=txmi1` and then, for istance, `{\aaa fghi}`, the output is empty.

The documentation of the txfont package (page 28 in the a4 form) shows how the txmi1 exists and in LaTeX can be used, but I cannot understand how to use it in plain TeX.

Comment: I have to add an important note: TeX gives no output, and dvips gives an error too, but if I compile with pdftex no errors appear, and even the font is shown.

Comment: If you get errors you should place the exact errors from the log in a `{}` block in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's a virtual font (`.vf`) but should work just as a normal font:

[image]

```
\font\zz=txmi1

abc [{\zz abc} ]

\bye
```

The font should be

```
$ kpsewhich txmi1.vf
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/public/txfonts/txmi1.vf
```

Comment: Is that command that gives me no output. Is it possible that dvips gives trouble?

Comment: @Lorenzo works for me with pdftex and tex/dvips/ps2pdf. You presumably don't have all the font installed, or the map entry for dvips or .... You should get a warning from tex or dvips or ps2pdf or something if the fonts do not appear at the end/

Comment: Whoever downvoted, why? I can't even guess?

Comment: That's right, my dvi viewer shows a warning. About the font installation, I'm sure I've installed all of those, even if I do not insert the fd files, which are required in LaTeX

Comment: the warning is the following: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\dvips.exe: ! Couldn't find font file n021023l.pfb

Comment: @Lorenzo Do you have ghostscript installed correctly? (Or whatever the equivalent is for Windows. Does Windows use ghostscript?) That's Nimbus Roman but under its ghostscript name. But I'd think it should be using the copy in your TeX installation `utmr...`?

Comment: Yes I'm using the clone utmr..., not the ptm... one. Should I have to use it?