# TXFonts in plain TeX

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, txfonts

I'm trying to get the same results of the LaTeX [`txfonts`](https://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts?lang=en) package in plain TeX.

I started with @DavidCarlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255324/134574) and it works fine... Unless I use spaces :P

This works exactly as expected:

```
\font\zz=txmi1
abc [{\zz abc} ]
\end
```

and produces this:

[image]

But if we go a little further and do this:

```
\font\zz=txmi1
Ol\'a mundo! [{\zz Ol\'a mundo!} ]
\end
```

things will get a little strange:

[image]

Why does this happen? And how to I get to replace correctly Computer Modern by TXFonts in plain TeX?

P.S.: Both standard TeX and PDFTeX produce the same result.

Comment: You have fallen on to the `\zz` side of the Force ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your font is a font meant for math. You can check its fonttable like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{txmi1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`txi` is probably the font you want:

```
\font\zz=txi
Ol\'a mundo! [{\zz Ol\'a mundo!} ]
\bye
```

[image]